# Is there a good way to run a single gremlin query from the command line?

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop

I'd like to run a single gremlin query, against a particular server, from the command line. (from my unix shell, not from the inside the Gremlin console)

I'm looking for something analogous to postgres' [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/app-psql.html) (e.g. `psql -c 'select * from "foo"'`).

### Longhand

Here's an example of what I want to do, interactively, using the [Gremlin Console](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/tutorials/the-gremlin-console/):

```
gremlin> cluster = Cluster.build('my-db-host').create()
==>my-db-host/127.0.0.1:8182
gremlin> :remote connect tinkerpop.server cluster
==>Configured my-db-host/127.0.0.1:8182
gremlin> :remote console
==>All scripts will now be sent to Gremlin Server - [my-db-host/127.0.0.1:8182] - type ':remote console' to return to local mode
gremlin> g.V().count()
==>1
```

### Gremlin Console `-e`?

Hoping to shorten this, the first place I looked is Gremlin Console's `-e`, where you can supply a groovy script to run.

I started with the above commands, but soon realized that the ":remote" commands [don't work](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.1.2-incubating/reference/#_script_executor) under -e.

So then I started building up [java client code](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.1.2-incubating/reference/#connecting-via-java) to run a query out of the groovy script's args[0] and print the results, but it seems like this is way more complicated than it needs to be.

Am I missing something obvious? Where's this ecosystem's equivalent of `psql -c`?

Are there any third-party clients out there that might offer what I'm after?

### *Update:*

I continued down the gremlin console path, and cobbled this together ([gist](https://gist.github.com/jrr/7ec736d830a87658cbb5333da8a39f9e)):

*`query.groovy`:*

```
println "Server: "+args[0]

cluster = Cluster.build(args[0]).create()
client = cluster.connect()

println "Query: "+args[1]

r = client.submit(args[1]).toList()

println "Result:"

r.each { println it }
```

*`gremlin-query.sh`:*

```sh
#! /usr/bin/env bash
SERVER=$1
QUERY=$2
if [ "$#" -ne 2 ]; then
    echo "Usage:"
    echo "./gremlin-query.sh localhost 'g.V().elementMap()'"
    exit 1
fi
./apache-tinkerpop-gremlin-console-3.4.10/bin/gremlin.sh -e query.groovy "$SERVER" "$QUERY"
```

The output looks like this:

```
> ./gremlin-query.sh localhost "g.V().elementMap()"
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass (file:/path/to/apache-tinkerpop-gremlin-console-3.4.10/lib/groovy-2.5.14-indy.jar) to method java.lang.Object.finalize()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
Server: localhost
Query: g.V().elementMap()
Result:
result{object={id=0, label=foobar} class=java.util.LinkedHashMap}
>
```

I wouldn't call this a *good way* to run a single query, so I'll leave the question open in hopes of something more like `psql` arriving in the future.

Answer (score 2):

As you have found, you can't use `-e` when using console commands but with a bit of trickery you can use `-i`. Usually you use `-i` to initialize the console into some state (e.g. establish your remote connection so that when you login you are all set to start writing Gremlin that will go to a server). The `-i` command does not write output from your commands though. Of course, you can write your script to explicitly `println()` results and then to auto-exit as `-e` would. For example, `try.groovy`:

```
:remote connect tinkerpop.server conf/remote.yaml
:> g.V().count()
println result
:x
```

produces this output:

```
$ bin/gremlin.sh -i try.groovy

         \,,,/
         (o o)
-----oOOo-(3)-oOOo-----
plugin activated: tinkerpop.server
plugin activated: tinkerpop.utilities
plugin activated: tinkerpop.neo4j
plugin activated: tinkerpop.tinkergraph
[result{object=6 class=java.lang.String}]
```

which might be good enough for your use case. Other than that, I think you would just stick with `-e` and work with the `Cluster` object directly.

Comment: Thanks for the sanity check. I continued down the `-e` / `Cluster` path, and added that to the question above. Do you think TinkerPop might offer a denser CLI tool in the future?

Comment: This is the first the issue has come up that I know of. I assume the community would be open to the idea if it were proposed.